# how do i create a dynamic view for data entry

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

What i want in the view is to spit out the fields that are part of the Department and Employee models depending on whichever one gets mentioned in the  URL.

say for example department model has 5 fields

How do i create a view (dynamic/not strongly typed) that automatically displays the fields based on the model and let the user enter the values?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(string process)
    {
        if (process.Equals("Department"))
        {
            var model = new Department();
            return View(model);
        }
        else if (process.Equals("Employee"))
        {
            var model = new Employee();
            return View(model);
        }
        else
            return View();
    }
```

Comment: Entirely doable, but a *really, really bad idea*.  You are definitely violating separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as an object. You could also pass it in the viewdata (or viewbag). For both of these ways you would also need to include a flag so you know which one you should cast to. Both of these ways in my opinion though are hokey and prone to problems.

Another way would be to create a view model that combines both models. I personally would try to keep them separate and use separate calls \ views for each, depending on the requirements.